# how can i turn Jquery UI autocomplete into links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i was trying out the jquery ui autocomplete and its pretty easy to implment and i loved it, but im finding it confusing to make the suggestions linkable just like google search,i.e when you click on it it takes you to another page.

```
$(function() {  
            $("#state").autocomplete({
                source: "states.php",
                minLength: 2,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $('#state_id').val(ui.item.id);
                    $('#abbrev').val(ui.item.abbrev);
                }
            });
});
```

this is an example of the jquery script, thanks for your help:))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need a line like:

```
window.location="http://place/to/link/to.php?" + ui.item.abbrev; //This would send you to a php script accepting ui.item.abbrev as a parameter.
```

in your `select : function(event,ui){ ... }`

Answer (score 2):

you can add a callback function to the select event.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

there you could redirect to the link you want.

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Sorry I just saw you have already the callback function added.
so you only need to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

This example should get you going to the right place: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data